# select option is not working in IOS for ionic 1 app

Tags: ios, angularjs, xcode, ionic-framework

select option is not displaying confirm button when i first time select dropdown. after the i select dropdown its work properly in ios and its working properly in android.

```
<select data-ng-options="o.name for o in distUnits track by o.id" ng-model="selectedOption" "></select>
```

in controller

```
$scope.distUnits = [{ name: "Meters", id: 1 }, { name: "Kilometers", id: 2 },{ name: "Miles", id: 3 }];
$scope.selectedOption = $scope.distUnits[0];
```

i have set `false` in my app.js file

```
$ionicPlatform.ready().then(function (){
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);
       cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 <select data-ng-options="o.id as o.name for o in distUnits track by o.id" 
        ng-model="selectedOption" "></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not displaying confirm button for the first time in IOS x-code simulator. after then if i click on dropdown its displaying confirm button.